# my nested loops in ksh doesn't substitute normally

Tags: ksh, substitution

The following script is getting data from file.csv
Inside I have the following:

```
user1,image1.jpg
user2,image2.jpg
```

I need to go with curl and download a file from

```
http://example.com/user1/default.jpg as image1.jpg
http://example.com/user2/default.jpg as image2.jpg
```

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/ksh

users=( $(awk -F "," '{print $1}' test.csv) )
image=( $(awk -F "," '{print $2}' test.csv) )
for (( i=0; i<${#users[@]}; i++ ))
do
    curl -o ${image[i]} http:://example.com/${users[i]}/default.jpg
done
```

The problem is that for the second array, it returns strange things like $'image1.jpg\r' instead of image1.jpg:

```
+ awk -F , '{print $1}' test.csv
+ users=( user1 user2 )
+ awk -F , '{print $2}' test.csv
+ image=( $'image1.jpg\r' $'image2.jpg\r' )
+ (( i=0))
+ (( i<2))
+ (( i=0))
+ (( i<2))
+ curl -o $'image1.jpg\r' http://example.com/user1/default.jpg
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    16  100    16    0     0   1008      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1333
+ ((i++ ))
+ (( i<2))
+ curl -o $'image2.jpg\r' http://example.com/user2/LThumb.jpg
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    16  100    16    0     0    976      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1230
+ ((i++ ))
+ (( i<2))
+ ((i++ ))
+ (( i<2))
```

Why doesn't substitute as expected?

Comment: Seems your second list ends with carriage returns. Clean those up with `dos2unix` or `tr -d '\r' < oldfile > newfile`

Comment: Why did you add the label `bash`, but your script is clearly `ksh`?

Comment: Why is `for (( i=0; i<${#image[@]}; i++ ))` needed if you only have one image per user? You should control the retrieval of images from `for (( i=0; i<${#users[@]}; i++ ))` and reference the corresponding image. You are using `i` as the loop variable for both loops.

Comment: @kojiro thanks mate. that was the problem. it works with the tr -d one.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin so how can I improve it?

Comment: Get rid of the `for (( i=0; i<${#image[@]}; i++ ))` loop altogether. (you see it is using the same `i` as `for (( i=0; i<${#users[@]}; i++ ))`) The arrays are **indexed** arrays, so you loop `0` to `${#users[@]}` and for each index you have 1-user and 1-image -- which you reference with a single index (e.g. both `0`, then both `1`, etc.)

Comment: good point mate.

Comment: Do not use the bash tag for a ksh script. And knowingly putting a misleading keyword in the title... wtf?!

Answer (score 2):

While you are free to use `awk` to split the file into arrays -- that isn't really the way file parsing is supposed to work in bash. bash provides very flexible file read and line parsing abilities on its own. You can use *parameter expansion with substring removal* to split each line into the *user* and *image* fields and make a call to `curl` to retrieve each image simply by looping over the file.

In bash the `${var#*,}` expansion will trim everything up to (and including) the first `','` from the *left*.

The `${var%,*}` expansion will trim everything up to (and including) the first `','` from the *right*.

(**note:** the different placement of the wildcard `'*'` in each)

This allows you to reduce your script to a fairly trivial:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r line; do
    curl -o "${line#*,}" "http://example.com/${line%,*}/default.jpg"
done < file.csv
```

**Example `curl` Calls**

Which when run on your example file will produce the following `curl` calls:

```
curl -o image1.jpg http://example.com/user1/default.jpg
curl -o image2.jpg http://example.com/user2/default.jpg
```

That appears to be what you are attempting -- and a lot simpler to do.

**note:** if you are potentially dealing with .csv file with non-POSIX end-of-file (no `'\n'` after the final line), then you can add the test `[ -n "$line ]` to your while loop condition to insure the final line is read, e.g.

```
while read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]; do
    curl -o "${line#*,}" "http://example.com/${line%,*}/default.jpg"
done < file.csv
```